# ajax response includes image, onClick event on image not working jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

im getting really crazy about this, i cant make a simple `click()` event in jQuery. i really need your help on this.

i have ajax that will send data to a PHP file and the result will echo back as `(response)`

```
$.post("get.php?data="+ data, {
  }, function(response){
  $('#load').html(response);
```

included in the response, is this `<img src="next.png" id="next" alt="" />`

i simply want the `next` image to be clickable and display some kind of alert.

below are my different variations on the code. but i still cant make the button work!

```
//test 1
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#next').livequery("click", function () {
        alert("test");
    });
});

//test 2
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#next').on("click", function () {
        alert("test");
    });
});

//test 3
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('img#next').on("click", function () {
        alert("test");
    });
});

//test 4
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#next').on("click", "img", function () {
        alert("test");
    });
});

//test 5
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#next').on("click", "img", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert("test");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

As elements are added dynamically you can not bind events directly to them .So you have to use [Event Delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/).

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on("click", "#next", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert("test");
    });
});
```

or better

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#load").on("click", "#next", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert("test");
    });
});
```

Syntax

```
$( elements ).on( events, selector, data, handler );
```

Comment: thank you! never knew about event delegation. thanks for saving me from headache.